# Apache 'You don't have permission to access xx on this server'

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

I am using ubuntu 12.04 and apache (new in both of them) and I want to add a new virtual directory so I modify the file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`, adding the following:

```
Alias /docs/ "/home/kk/workspace/javascript/maplib/"
<Directory "/home/kk/workspace/javascript/maplib/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

Then I open the url `http://localhost/docs/` in the browser and I get the following message:

```
You don't have permission to access /docs/ on this server.
```

Then I think it may be caused by the file/folder permission. So I add the `read` permession to all users by:

```
sudo chmod a+r /home/kk/workspace/javascript/maplib/
```

Then I run

```
ls -ld ~/workspace/javascript/maplib/
```

and I got this:

```
drwxr--r-- 14 kk kk 4096 Mar 11 08:36 /home/kk/workspace/javascript/maplib/
```

As you can see every user shold have the `read` access to the directory, but nothing changed ( I also get the `403` message).

Then I try to find the permission of `/var/www` and I get:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar  8 15:33 /var/www
```

It seems that it just add the `execute` permission to the folder, but I do not think this is the problem.

So what is going on?

---

BTW, why does apache identify `/docs` and `/docs/` with two different url? Since I will get `404` by `localhost/docs`?

Comment: @ultranaut:Thanks for your edition. :)

Comment: did you restart apache after you made the changes to the config file?

Comment: Ofcouse,I restart it use `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Apache installation access is controlled using etc/apache2/envars and implemented in etc/apache2/apache2.conf

In /etc/apache2/apache2.conf you will find the following lines about half way down a the file.

```
#These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envars
    User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
    Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
```

In /etc/apache2/envars you will find

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
```

The directories you want the webserver to access need to be in the group running the webserver. I would say to check the group permissions and fix them if necessary. If you have these set correctly come back and post the Apache access logs.