# Install Apache 2.4.7 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I have a following problem.
Install Apache 2.4.7 on Ubuntu.
I created file in directory /etc/apache2/sites-available/

```
<VirtualHost ooo.net:80>

ServerName ooo.net
ServerAlias www.ooo.net
ServerAdmin webmaster@ooo.net
DocumentRoot /home/user/ooo/

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

in hosts

```
127.0.0.1   ooo.net
127.0.1.1   pc
```

I visited ooo.net and saw following result

*Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80*

What am I doing wrong?

error.log -

```
[Sat Apr 12 19:30:57.276525 2014] [core:error] [pid 1213:tid 140219565360896] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:37136] AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/home/user/ooo') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
[Sat Apr 12 19:30:57.539816 2014] [core:error] [pid 1213:tid 140219556968192] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:37136] AH00035: access to /favicon.ico denied (filesystem path '/home/user/ooo') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
```

access.log -

```
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Apr/2014:19:30:57 +0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 495 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/33.0.1750.152 Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Apr/2014:19:30:57 +0400] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 505 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/33.0.1750.152 Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36"
```

ls -ltr after first answer -

```
drwxr-sr-x 2 user www-data   4096 апр.  10 20:41 errors
-rwxr-sr-x 1 user www-data   9062 апр.  10 20:41 about.htm
-rwxr-sr-x 1 user www-data   7116 апр.  10 20:41 admin.htm
-rwxr-sr-x 1 user www-data   2884 апр.  10 20:41 admin_art.inc
-rwxr-sr-x 1 user www-data 367112 апр.  10 20:41 ARIAL.TTF
-rwxr-sr-x 1 user www-data   4767 апр.  10 20:41 admin_d2.inc
-rwxr-sr-x 1 user www-data   2958 апр.  10 20:41 admin_exb.inc
-rwxr-sr-x 1 user www-data   2369 апр.  10 20:41 admin_faq.inc
-rwxr-sr-x 1 user www-data   1846 апр.  10 20:41 admin_fbk.inc
-rwxr-sr-x 1 user www-data   1791 апр.  10 20:41 admin_fbk2.inc
-rwxr-sr-x 1 user www-data   2657 апр.  10 20:41 admin_gbk.inc
-rwxr-sr-x 1 user www-data   3881 апр.  10 20:41 admin_frm.inc
-rwxr-sr-x 1 user www-data   2616 апр.  10 20:41 admin_gbl.inc
-rwxr-sr-x 1 user www-data   8197 апр.  10 20:41 admin_img.inc
-rwxr-sr-x 1 user www-data   7352 апр.  10 20:41 admin_new.inc
```

Comment: what do you get when you issue ls -ltr command on /home/user/ooo/? Also, look through the access.log and post the relevant lines for your error.

Comment: -ltr don't work - "unknown command". I added some details in question

Comment: The command is ls -ltr.. you need the ls in front as it is the command. the -ltr part are the arguments. It will list the dirs and ownership rights. The error log has your details above, you are lacking the correct rights on your Docroot. Your docroot should be owned by www-data.

Comment: all files in folder 'ooo' has rights '-rwxr-xr-x' except some including folders (drwxr-xr-x).

Comment: not enough info. I guarantee the www-data user can't access your docroot because you moved it off /var/www/ into a your secure home dir. Your permissions are incorrect. Add www-data user to your user group and see what happens. Next time paste the output of ls -ltr, its not enough to explain the dir permissions without the owner.

Comment: how it do? 'sudo chown www-data:www-data /home/user/ooo'?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem relies in the fact that Apache default configuration is a bit more restrictive from 2.4.3 onwards. Directories outside the default Document Root are prohibited by default and have to be enabled explicitly. See: [Install Apache web server on Ubuntu 13.10](http://www.binarytides.com/install-apache-ubuntu-13-10/)

Basically you should add:

```
Require all granted
```

Underneath somewhere under the Directory directive.

Answer (score 2):

Your webserver is running as www-data. Therefore you need to add the user account that owns your new docroot to this www-data group using the following command.

```
xxx$ sudo usermod -a -G groupName userName
```

where groupname is www-data and userName is your username that owns the docroot.

You can reference this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15329974/apache-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-xx-on-this-server/15348580#15348580) that explains why you are doing this.

Lastly, that command I asked you to execute the first time, ls -ltr would have provided all the info I needed to answer this yesterday. If your going to ask questions, please provide the details asked for when asked.

Hope this helps,
Pat

Comment: I use this command: '$ sudo usermod -a -G www-data user'. User - single my user. Nothing has changed. I added in my question details ls -ltr

Comment: The ls -ltr output above is on the dir user and is not correct. You chowned your user dir to www-data without anyone's suggestion. The only thing you needed to do was add your user to the www-data group. Your /home/user dir should be owned by you. Like I said you have a permission problem and you do not at all understand Linux security. Apache installs and runs correctly out of the box until you change something incorrectly. Since you moved the docroot off it's default location you need to set the correct permissions. Your problem above is the same as the one I answered and linked to above.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case any other user have same problem. From Ubuntu 14.04, if you are hosting virtual host outside of /var/www or /usr/share, you need to add the path to white list in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf. In this case, like this

```
<Directory /home/user/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Of course, permission need to be granted like @ptheo suggested

Answer (score 1):

They changed something with how they handle files. By default apache can only access files in /var/www or /usr/share. I just changed my folder over to be under /usr/share and the necessary configurations and voila. There is more guidance in the default index.html file at /var/www/html/index.html. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Try**

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/user/ooo
```

to give the right permissions to the DocumentRoot

Answer (score 0):

Terminal commands ubuntu

## Install Apache

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install apache2`

`/etc/apache2/sites-available$ sudo gedit 000-default.conf`

### Inside that file, you will find the <VirtualHost *:80> .</VirtualHost>. Inside of line

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
           Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
           allow from all
</Directory>
```

## restart Apache.

sudo service apache2 restart`